# How to customize animation for angular2-material tabs so that animation of content is based on tab selected?

Tags: angular, angular-material

So I am trying out angular-material (angular2-material) and have noticed that by default when using tabs, whenever I select a tab the content flies in from the right. is there a way to make it such that when I select a tab that is to the left of the tab current selected, that the content flies in from the left? I am looking for a programattic creation of the tabs from an array. So I assume my I have an object "`this.tabs=[{label:"Tab 1", "content": "Content 1"}, {label:"Tab 2":"content": "Content 2"}, ...]"`

So my tabs look like this in the template...

```
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 3">Content 2</md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 4">Content 2</md-tab>
<md-tab label="Tab 5">Content 2</md-tab>
<md-tab label="Tab 6">Content 2</md-tab>
<md-tab label="Tab 7">Content 2</md-tab>
<md-tab label="Tab 8">Content 2</md-tab>
<md-tab label="Tab 9">Content 2</md-tab>
<md-tab label="Tab 10">Content 2</md-tab>
<md-tab label="Tab 11">Content 2</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

What do I need to do to get correct animations?

Comment: I was just working on a plunker related to md-tab.. content flys in from the direction of the currently selected tab.. check this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/uJ3n8XedvCCdeUHXKpwX?p=preview. Also I dont see an option to change it, you cam look at animation source here: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/tabs/tab-body.ts

Comment: to me it works only when router is not involved... but anytime I change the route... the content always flies from the right, no matter the tab position (the tabs do animate correctly though).... @Rolando have you solved it?